# Make iTunes delete old listened podcasts (after a while)

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I would like iTunes to automatically delete the downloaded file after I had listened to it. Ideally I would like to be able to keep them for a few days after I had listened to it but it's not necessary.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to control Podcast longevity is built into iTunes (although the options are limited).

Select “Podcasts” in iTunes and the Settings button should be visible in the lower part of the iTunes window:
[image: podcast settings]